# Store Data from Field as a txt file on server (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, unix

Im trying to upload a plain text file to a server from my javascript form. When you hit submit, I need to store a text file on my server so that my translator program can read the file. Please see my project and it will make sense
[Link to my project](http://lknbt.net/melt/project_77571/)

Comment: You need to give more detail: what server architecture? Can your translator program read from a database? How are you currently serving the page?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You generally need some sort of server-side scripting in order to affect the server in any way (javascript is client-side). Are you using any server-side languages? e.g. PHP, ASP.NET, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just submit the form holding the text value and generate the text file on the server?

Comment: I would love to but Im not sure how

Comment: Well, you know how to submit a `form` right? What server-side language are you using?